# Integrate ESLint with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, eslint

I am using ESLint for JavaScript. I installed it in my machine and am able to run and check for the errors in the file that I want to. Everything is good but if I have to use it only from command prompt I have to manually run this for each file or a folder. I am thinking about integrating this into Visual Studio so that when I run it like "Run ESLint on solution" it will give a list of warnings/errors for all the JS files in the solution. Even if we can't do that, is it possible to select a file and to run ESLint on that file in Visual Studio 2015?

I added ESLint to external tools in Visual Studio:

[image]

But when I run it, it's not showing any errors or anything. It is just showing the details of the help command. How do I run this on a particular file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `$(ItemPath)` in the arguments textbox to specify the file you want to lint otherwise `$(ProjDir)` for linting the entire project at once. if you managed to figgure that out already i leave this here for generations to come

Answer (score 10):

Web Analyzer extension has now been built in to Visual Studio in the .NET Core Tooling Preview 1

Follow the link to download the installer for
[**.NET Core Tooling Preview 1**](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core)

You can install Web Analyzer extension as well, but after the restart you will get a prompt:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? The fact that ESLint is now officially integrated with Visual Studio 2015 (as of this month) is great news and is very relevant to this question.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to reformulate to look more like an answer.
Also it is better to provide a link to a page, generic if possible, rather than directly to an exe file which might be soon obsolete.

Comment: Bugs in the .NET Core Tooling Preview prevented this working for me. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/727) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/980) on github.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [WebAnalyzer plugin for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6edc26d4-47d8-4987-82ee-7c820d79be1d), which does JavaScript linting through ESLint. It should highlight javascript errors every time you save your file, so it's a bit nicer then doing it through the menu. If you don't want to use plugin, you can setup a new menu item in the Tools > External Programs menu. Make sure to use ESLint's [visual studio formatter](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/#visualstudio) that should allow you to double-click on the error and have Visual Studio take you to the line where the error occurred.

Comment: Yeah I read about Web analyzer yesterday.  I will try the second option too.  Thanks